# Making a dictionary where key is a list

Tags: python

so given a list of dictionaries:

```
    my_dict= [{'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '1', 'd': '3'},  
              {'a': '1', 'b': '8', 'c': '1', 'd': '2'},
              {'a': '7', 'b': '4', 'c': '1', 'd': '5'}]
```

and a list of keys in the dictionary for example [ 'a', 'b']
I am trying to make a list of dictionaries for both 'a' and 'b' for their respective values i.e the final product will resemble

```
    new_dict = ['a':['4', '1', '7'], 'b':['5', '8', '4']]
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: `new_dict` is an invalid syntax and hence impossible

Comment: In one line: `new_dict = {k:[d[k] for d in my_dict] for k in list_of_keys}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections`

**Demo:**

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
my_dict= [{'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '1', 'd': '3'}, {'a': '1', 'b': '8', 'c': '1', 'd': '2'}, {'a': '7', 'b': '4', 'c': '1', 'd': '5'}]
for i in my_dict:
    for k,v in i.items():
        d[k].append(v)
print( d )
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['4', '1', '7'], 'c': ['1', '1', '1'], 'b': ['5', '8', '4'], 'd': ['3', '2', '5']})
```

Comment: can it be done without importing collections?